# Show multiple files inside storage folder with unknown names Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, file, foreach, directory

I have a laravel project 
and I have some folders inside storage folders like this

```
storage\app\public\archives\user_id\file1    
storage\app\public\archives\user_id\file2    
storage\app\public\archives\user_id\file3
```

now, I don't know the name of the files and I don't know the extensions of them also 
how can I run foreach based on user_id to show all files inside user_id folder like this example.

```
$files  = Storage::get(); // get files inside user_id folder only
foreach($files as $file)
{
    // fun my code here 
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the `File` facade to achieve this.

For example:

```
$files = File::files(storage_path("app/public/archives/{$user->id}"));
```

*Replace `$user->id` with your actual user id.*

This will return an array of [SplFileInfo](http://php.net/manual/en/class.splfileinfo.php) objects, which means you can now do this:

```
foreach($files as $file) {
    echo $file->getBasename(); 
}
```

Check the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/class.splfileinfo.php) on SplFileInfo to have an idea of what's possible.